Spring Cloud Stream Multiple Binders With Dynamic Host
I am using Spring Cloud Stream and I need to use two rabbbitmq binders at the same time. For example local-binder and external-binder. I did some research and found a configuration like below
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        local-rabbit:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5671
        external-rabbit
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: 192.168.... // this should be dynamic
                port: 5672

external-rabbit connection will not always be open, I want to get the host value for external-rabbit dynamically via ui and I want to close the connection dynamically. How can I do this?
